# How can I fix this lambda conditional?

Tags: lambda, boolean

This is the code I'm confused with:

```
starts_with_J = lambda x: True if x.startswith('J' or '1') else False
print(starts_with_J('1Ji'))
```

I want the system to give me 'True' if the input string starts with either 'J' or '1', and 'False' otherwise. However when I put a string that starts with '1', the result is 'False'. How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the conditions:

```
starts_with_J = lambda x: True if x.startswith('J') or x.startswith('1') else False
```

---

This may also work:

```
lambda x: x.startswith('J') or x.startswith('1')
```